# GIL Deadlock when thread raise an exception

Tags: python, gil

if a thread raises an exception, would it not release the GIL and cause deadlock?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this? Perhaps show some code that illustrates what the issue/scenario you're describing is. If a thread raises an exception that isn't caught, the process is terminated, for starters, so I assume you're talking about a caught exception? Thanks.

Comment: It is quite simple. A thread is running into exception, but not be caught. Because the thread is holding the GIL, will it release it and so that other threads can run normally?

Comment: In that scenario, the exception brings the entire process down like I said, so what you're asking doesn't really make sense to me. Try it and see!

Comment: A MCVE would be `Thread(target=lambda: 5//0).start()`, but if you caught the exception I think the question you're posing might be more interesting. Also, if you're asking this in conjunction with a concern you have about some concrete code you're working on, adding context might be helpful. What's the motivation for asking, in other words?

Comment: This is just what I suddenly thought of, thanks a lot.